# .NET Core Windows Forms app: can't find System.Timers.Timer in visual studio 2019 toolbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, toolbox, system.timers.timer

Starting an app in Visual Studio 2019. It is a Windows Forms app using .NET Core 5.
I have used System.Timers.Timer previously and found it to be of low jitter.
However, I am not able to find it in Visual Studio toolbox.
There is a timer under All Windows Forms it is: System.Windows.Forms.Timer
There is another timer under Components, it is also System.Windows.Forms.Timer.
This timer is not reliable. The numbers of ticks vary quite a bit from what is specified.
Fallback is to construct a System.Timers.Timer by hand.
Looking at my previous app though it came from the toolbox.
Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to run speed tests? Have you ever used Stopwatch? It's convenient for speed tests.

Comment: I don't think `System.Timers.Timer` was ever in the WinForm's Designer Toolbox.

Comment: Andrew Reese: have a state machine in the tick handler. I need about 20 ticks in a minute. 
LarsTech: here is code parts from the previous app: (in designer.cs) 
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.timerSys)).BeginInit();
in:
 #region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>

I am afraid the build will kick my manual inserts out.

Comment: You can always add a System.Timers.Timer object in the designer code behind, outside of the region `InitializeComponent` method.

Comment: @LarsTech https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2004/february/comparing-the-timer-classes-in-the-net-framework-class-library says it used to be (i don't remember it either)

Answer (score -2):

As others said, [System.Timers.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-5.0) can not be found in the Toolbox.

Because it doesn't inherit from [System.Windows.Forms.Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control?view=net-5.0) class. It is not a windows form control.

You can refer to the following code to know how to use it in winforms.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        }
        System.Timers.Timer timer;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
            timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;

        }

        private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText("Hello, world"+Environment.NewLine);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Please provide some justification for turning off cross thread checking rather than adopting one of the Microsft advocated routes of accessing controls in a not-the-thread-that-created-it scenario (e.g. Invoke or setting SyncronizingObject property)

Comment: Thank you. I was able to place relevant code in te form1 constructor. It is working fine. I still think/recall at some point it was possible to pull it out of the toolbox/components.

Comment: @HBC531, I have explained that why it can not be found in toolbox.  Please check it again. I think there is no affect if the timer can be pull out of the toolbox when you use it.